# $\pi_*(X)$ $2$-torsion then $H_*(X,\mathbb{Q})=\{0\}=H_*(X,\mathbb{Z}_{p^k})$ with $p$ odd

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

While reading the proof a certain statement this came up. Let $X$ be a topological space such that $\pi_k(X)$ is a $2$-torison for all $k$, then $H_*(X,\mathbb{Q})=\{0\}=H_*(X,\mathbb{Z}_{p^k})$ with $p$ an odd prime.

I am trying to see why this statement is true. For the fact $H_*(X,\mathbb{Q})=\{0\} $ we could use the rational version of Hurewicz theorem to obtain the desired result, altough I am not sure this is not an overkill.

For the fact that $H_*(X,\mathbb{Z}_{p^k})=\{0\}$ I am not sure what can I do. I don't know if there is a Hurewicz theorem I can apply in this case.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\pi_4(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but $H_*(S^2; \mathbb{Q})$ is not zero.

Comment: If $X$ satisfies your hypothesis, then so does $X\times S^2$, but Kunneth shows the conclusion is false for the latter space.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that $\pi_k(X)$ is a finite $2$-torsion group for all $k$. Serre's theory of classes of abelian groups ought to help in that case.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant @JohnPalmieri, I will edit.

Comment: Note that "has 2-torsion" is not the same as being a "2-torsion group".

Comment: Localizing the space at $p$ should do the trick. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_topological_space

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more ? I'm not sure how the result will follow. @CheerfulParsnip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article I linked above, you can solve this through localizing your space. Let $R=\mathbb Z[1/2]$ be the ring where you invert the prime $2$. Let $X_{loc}$ be this localization. Then $H_*(X_{loc};\mathbb Z)\cong H_*(X;R)$ and $\pi_*(X_{loc})\cong X\otimes R$. By assumption $X\otimes R=0,$ so the homotopy groups of $X_{loc}$ are trivial. Then by Whitehead's theorem, $X_{loc}$ has the weak homotopy type of a point, and so $H_*(X_{loc};\mathbb Z)\cong 0$ above degree $0$. Hence $H_*(X;R)\cong 0$. To finish, we consider the long exact sequence in homology corresponding to the short exact sequence of coefficient modules:
$$0\to p^kR\to R\to \mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z\to 0,$$
which exists because $p$ is odd. The homology with respect to $R$ was just shown to be trivial, and so will be the homology with respect to $p^kR$ as it is isomorphic to that with respect to $R$. Hence, the homology with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$ are also trivial.

Comment: Actually, this only works if $\pi_1(X)=0$, but you can fix it by first passing to the universal cover.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Do you know if both of these results generalize to spectra ? That is if the homotopy groups of spectra are $2$-torsion then these homology with coefficients, of the spectrum, must vanish ?@CheerfulParsnip

Comment: @what Sorry, I am rather ignorant when it comes to spectra.

Comment: @What This is true. For any spectrum $X$ we have $H_\ast(X;\mathbb{Q})\cong\pi_\ast(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$. For any prime $p$, let $X/p^k$ be the cofiber of multiplication by $p^k$. If $p$ is odd, then $X/p^k\simeq 0$ and since smashing with a fixed spectrum preserves cofiber sequences, $X/p^k\wedge H\mathbb{Z}\simeq X\wedge H\mathbb{Z}/p^k$. The left hand side is contractible and the homotopy groups of the right hand side are $H_\ast(X;\mathbb{Z}/p^k)$.